# apply a function to different data.frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I´m a newbie R and I would like to ask the following question.

I have a group of data.frames with 2 columns, and I´d like to apply a function to eac data.frame without typing the name of the data.frame each time, i.e:

The data.frames would be: a, b, c, d, ......... and each data.frame has 2 columns with 
different row length:

```
 a[1:4]
V1         V2
1   877.0578   609.0308
2   989.5682   160.1206
3  1049.5844   143.2906
4  1111.5798   214.5290
```

I would like to apply the following function to each data.frame,
This is the function which I would like to apply

```
  as.MassPeaks <- function(x) {return(createMassPeaks(mass=mass(x), intensity=intensity(x),metaData=metaData(x)))}
```

I have a vector (names) with all the data.frame names
I´ve tried the following code but it didn´t work

```
 for(i in length(names)){
    assign(i, createMassPeaks(mass=i[, 1], intensity=i[, 2]))
    }
```

However when I try with a single data.frame it works

```
 p <- createMassPeask(mass=a[,1], intensity=[, 2])
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Be careful with your copying and pasting- you have a number of typos, including in the code that you say works( for instance, `createMassPeask(mass=a[,1], intensity=[, 2])` should be `createMassPeaks(mass=a[,1], intensity=a[, 2])`) and that makes it harder to answer your question.

Comment: Note that working with the actual names of data frames (as in your vector `names`) is generally not recommended. It is much better to keep them in a list. If you actually did want to work with the names of each, you could use `get` (but again, don't).

Answer (score 2):

You want to put the data frames into a list, and then use `lapply` to create a list out of that:

```
data.frames = list(a, b, c, d)
mass.peaks.each = lapply(data.frames, as.MassPeaks)
```

Now `mass.peaks.each` is a list of of the results from each.

Incidentally, I think you want to change `as.MassPeaks` to:

```
  as.MassPeaks <- function(x) {return(createMassPeaks(mass=mass(x[, 1]), intensity=intensity(x[, 2]),metaData=metaData(x)))}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help David, your method is ellegant and functional

Comment: @JuanFernandezTajes when an answer (if and only if) meets your needs you should accept it and upvote it. David Robinson's the one you should accept

Answer (score 2):

Your `for` fails because you forget to use `get` function

```
library(MALDIquant)  # You should write what package is used

`Names <- c('a', 'b','c')` # this a vector of names

for(i in Names){
  assign(i, createMassPeaks(mass=get(i)[, 1], intensity=get(i)[, 2]))
}
```

This loop should work. Let's test it

```
set.seed(001)
a <- data.frame(V1=rnorm(50, 1000, 50), V2=rnorm(50, 1000, 50))
b <- data.frame(V1=rnorm(50, 1000, 50), V2=rnorm(50, 1000, 50))
c <- data.frame(V1=rnorm(50, 1000, 50), V2=rnorm(50, 1000, 50))
```

The result looks like this:

```
> a
S4 class type            : MassPeaks           
Number of m/z values     : 50                  
Range of m/z values      : 889.265 - 1079.764  
Range of intensity values: 9.098e+02 - 1.12e+03
> b
S4 class type            : MassPeaks            
Number of m/z values     : 50                   
Range of m/z values      : 904.282 - 1104.358   
Range of intensity values: 9.256e+02 - 1.115e+03
> c
S4 class type            : MassPeaks            
Number of m/z values     : 50                   
Range of m/z values      : 855.554 - 1124.883   
Range of intensity values: 8.798e+02 - 1.132e+03
```

In spite of this `for` loop works well, @David Robinson's answer is the best one. 
I want to say one more thing, I think your function should look like this:

```
as.MassPeaks <- function(x) {
  return(createMassPeaks(mass=x[, 1], 
                         intensity=x[, 2],
                         metaData=x))}
```

`mass=x[, 1]` works but `mass=mass(x[, 1])` does not, the same for `instensity` and `metaData`. Then using David Robinson's approach you should get:

```
lapply(list(a,b,c), as.MassPeaks)
[[1]]
S4 class type            : MassPeaks           
Number of m/z values     : 50                  
Range of m/z values      : 889.265 - 1079.764  
Range of intensity values: 9.098e+02 - 1.12e+03

[[2]]
S4 class type            : MassPeaks            
Number of m/z values     : 50                   
Range of m/z values      : 904.282 - 1104.358   
Range of intensity values: 9.256e+02 - 1.115e+03

[[3]]
S4 class type            : MassPeaks            
Number of m/z values     : 50                   
Range of m/z values      : 855.554 - 1124.883   
Range of intensity values: 8.798e+02 - 1.132e+03
```